# Confusion Understanding MATLAB ''PLOT'' command?

Tags: matlab

We know digital computer cannot deal with continuous time signals directly. But then how MATLAB "plot" command works?  Does that uses interpolation techniques

Below is link of a MATLAB central  question which is like  this same issue

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/512043-matlab-deals-only-with-discrete-signals

Comment: `plot` plots the points that your give to it and combines them with a straight line.

Comment: Dear usama, is it not the same process as interpolation, where we connect different points with straight lines?

Comment: No, it is not interpolation

Comment: I'm not sure if you are aware of the difference between the term *interpolation* (which always returns discrete points) and *line*, which is either a visualization element or an analytical description of the same (remember that two points define a line... so there is no interpolation...)

Comment: I have updated my question, please kindly consider now

Answer (score 2):

`plot(x,y)` simply plots a straight line of `Y` vs `X` with no interpolation. 
Do not confuse the *visualization* of a straight line on your screen with the actual data in `x(:)` and `y(:)`. Using `plot(x,y,'o')`, for example, would plot the points only.

Comment: `x(:)` => `(:)` is a syntax in MATLAB that [linearizes](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/35811-convert-matrix-in-single-column) a variable `x` into a column. e.g.:

`x=[1 2 ; 3  4]` => `x(:) = [1 2 3 4]'`